# Discrepancy between regression and crude analysis

Tags: regression

I was looking at a United States temperature dataset. One field is the year and month, the other is how much the temperature changed the previous 12 months. I was having a discussion with someone who mentioned that there was a general cooling of the US from 1895 until now ( when the data starts) until now, but the trend reversed around 1970's, only to rebound now.

```
            Cooler                  Warmer  
Years       Count   Avg ± Error     Count   Avg ± Error
1896-Now    887     -2.7 ± 0.2      590     1.0 ± 0.21
1975-Now    251     -1.8 ± 0.38     285     1.7 ± 0.29
```

A crude analysis definitely supports that.
However, when I perform a linear regression, there is a statistically significant increase in temperature in the dataset. From 1896 to now 0.03 deg / year, and from 1975 until now 0.1 deg / year.

I don't know if this is some advanced type of Will Rogers effect that I just can't parse, or I've done something more basic wrong.

Thanks for your help.

[Full Dataset Here](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/temp-and-precip/national-temperature-index/time-series?datasets%5B%5D=climdiv&parameter=anom-tavg&time_scale=p12&begyear=1895&endyear=2019&month=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crude analysis is appropriately named and doesn't really answer the question of an overall trend very well.

Linear regression of temperature on time is *slightly* better, but you really want to use time series methods that account for seasonality at the very least - more sophisticated models are certainly possible. I'd also be careful to check that what is measured is the same thing over time.

Another, simpler choice is, in the link, to use the annual time rather than what you used. You can then look at each month, separately. For each month, the plot shows clearly that temperatures were more-or-less steady until 1975 or 1980 and have been rising since. However, that doesn't seem to be able to give you equations.

Comment: Thank you very much,  I will look into time series analysis techniques.

Do you think you could explain why the two analyses give contradictory results? There is a face validity in looking at my above analysis, and saying more, stronger temperature drops means an overall temperature drop.

Thanks again for taking the time to answer

Comment: The crude analysis is asking a different question than the regression, but neither is really asking what you want to ask.

Comment: The crude is asking how many deviations in each direction, and what is their magnitude. It seems to me to be just another way of asking what is the trend.